# Python - For Loop through items within dictionary of lists in Selenium

Tags: python, list, selenium, for-loop

Sorry for the confusing title, but I hope the description makes more sense.

I'd like to iterate through a list of items, but because of the way that the website is structured, I first have to click the category it belongs to before I can access the item. For example, let's assume that this is my list of lists:

```
list_of_list = {"Animals": ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"],
                "Plants": ["Tree", "Flower"]}
```

To describe the process, it would look something like this: click on Animals, then on dog; click on Animals, then on Cat; click on Animals, then on Fish; click on Plants, then on Tree; click on Plants, then on Flower.

Normally, if the items belonged to one list, the code would look something like this:

```
list: ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish", "Tree", "Flower"]

For x in list:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[value="{}"]'.format(x)).click()
```

But how would I iterate through list of lists?

Comment: `list_of_list` doesn't actually looks like *list of lists*, but more like *dict of lists...*

Comment: Isn't it possible to iterate through this under a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there should be something like

```
categories = driver.find_elements_by_css_celector('.categories')
for category in categories:
    items = category.find_elements_by_css_selector(.item)
    for item in items:
        category.click()
        item.click()
        # do something with each item
```

This should allow you to click category and each item within this category

Comment: thanks for the quick response. If I could ask, would this take into consideration that some items belong to specific categories, or does it simply iterate through everything?

Comment: It should iterate through *all* categories and each item within category... Do you want to handle only specific (not all) categories?

Comment: I want to handle all items in all categories. I made an edit to my original post to visualize how the list of list of items looks like.

Comment: It would be easier to understand the issue if you provide with `HTML` sample (it can be simplified) for the same

Comment: I'll try your original idea first before posting the `HTML` sample. Thanks so much again in advance!